# Which is the secure way of reading the data from the Azure IoT hub?

Tags: azure, iot, azure-iot-hub

I am working on internet of things, in one of my current project I am reading the data from Azure IoT hub in a Windows 10 UWP app, where I am passing my IoT Hub connection string to azure while reading data( using Cloud to Device concept).

Is it secure/fine way or not reading data from a client app.

Thanks,
Pradeep

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The library uses https, however the contents of the message is not encrypted, so if you're super-sceptical, just encrypt it before sending.

Comment: Thanks Pedro G. Dias